# Default .Options setting for unzip

Tags: r, configuration, unzip

I was trying to install [ramnathv's `slidify` package](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify) and was surprised the by the following error:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("slidify","ramnathv")
Installing github repo slidify/master from ramnathv
Downloading slidify.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip
Installing package from /tmp/RtmpOFEJuD/slidify.zip
Error in unzip(src, exdir = target, unzip = getOption("unzip")) : 
  'unzip' must be a single character string
```

I've installed it before with no issues on another system using the same Arch Linux setup and their R package, granted it was an earlier version of R (3.0.0 or 3.0.1).

In googling the error, it comes from this bit in `zip.R`:

```
unzip <-
    function(zipfile, files = NULL, list = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE,
             junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal",
             setTimes = FALSE)
{
    if(identical(unzip, "internal")) {
        if(!list && !missing(exdir))
            dir.create(exdir, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
        res <- .External(C_unzip, zipfile, files, exdir, list, overwrite,
                         junkpaths, setTimes)
        if(list) {
            dates <- as.POSIXct(res[[3]], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",  tz="UTC")
            data.frame(Name = res[[1]], Length = res[[2]], Date = dates,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        } else invisible(attr(res, "extracted"))
    } else {
        WINDOWS <- .Platform$OS.type == "windows"
        if(!is.character(unzip) || length(unzip) != 1L || !nzchar(unzip))
            stop("'unzip' must be a single character string")

...
```

While the [default setting for `unzip()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/unzip.html) is `unzip = "internal"`, it can also be passed `getOptions("unzip")`:

```
Usage

unzip(zipfile, files = NULL, list = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE,
      junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal",
      setTimes = FALSE)

...

unzip
The method to be used. An alternative is to use getOption("unzip"),
which on a Unix-alike may be set to the path to a unzip program.
```

In looking at the output of `.Options`, I see, indeed, that there's nothing set for `unzip`:

```
> .Options$unzip
[1] ""
```

From perusing documentation, I see that I can set this in `~/.Renviron`, but my question is whether on a Linux system this should be picked up by default or if it's pretty standard to have to set your `unzip` command?

If it's *not* standard that this be un-populated, I'll file a bug report with Arch Linux, as perhaps the package was compiled without this as a default, as [documentation seems to suggest](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html) that it would be populated with an unzip command if one was found during installation:

```
unzip
a character string, the path of the command used for unzipping help files, or
"internal". Defaults to the value of R_UNZIPCMD, which is set in ‘etc/Renviron’
if an unzip command was found during configuration.
```

The Arch package I'm using is a binary and thus was pre-compiled, so intentionally or unintentionally perhaps this was overlooked or should be checked for during installation?

---

P.S. Just to avoid the obvious...

```
$ which unzip
/usr/bin/unzip
```

Comment: I ran into that issue a while back.  I just modified the .Renviron file.  I think part of the issue is that unzip isn't assumed to be installed on all Arch systems so how could you include it in a binary?

Comment: @Dason I wondered that myself. Though I'm curious why this worked on a previous version of Arch's binary! I filed a bug report, which may result in responding with that exact comment. I modified `~/.Renviron` with successful results just now, adding `R_UNZIPCMD=/usr/bin/unzip`.

Comment: @Hendy ran into this issue too. How about your bug report ? The Renviron file shall be changed definitively

Comment: @Hendy I corrected the Arch wiki. Please tell me your bug report number

Comment: @gabx [Here it is](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/38030)

Comment: @Hendy TY, I added one comment. Not sure thus we can call this a **bug** , but there is certainly something to modify in the _Renviron.in_ file.

Comment: Understood, and I now follow why one can't assume zip/unzip exists when installing the R package. Wondering about a pacman post-install message as an alternative? Similar to the optional dependency message that spits out with some packages -- something like `Note: please add xxxx to your ~/.Renviron file in order to enable unzip, which is required when installing certain R packages`?